# How to compute characteristic vector in SAS proc anova

Tags: sas

SAS code:

```
DATA aaa;
INPUT  x1 x2 group @@;
CARDS;
3.9 210 1          4.8      270    2           4.4      250    3
4.2 190 1          4.7      180    2           3.7      305    3
3.7 240 1          5.4      230    2           2.9      240    3
4.0 170 1          4.5      245    2           4.5      330    3
4.4 220 1          4.6      270    2           3.3      230    3
5.2 230 1          4.4      220    2           4.5      195    3
2.7 160 1          5.9      290    2           3.8      275    3
2.4 260 1          5.5      220    2           3.7      310    3
3.6 240 1          4.3      290    2          
5.5 180 1          5.1      310    2          
2.9 200 1          
3.3 300 1          
;
PROC ANOVA ;
CLASS group;
MODEL x1 x2=group;
MANOVA H=group/PRINTH PRINTE SUMMARY;
RUN;
quit;
```

SAS output：

```
     Characteristic Roots and Vectors of: E Inverse * H, where
                  H = Anova SSCP Matrix for group
                       E = Error SSCP Matrix

     Characteristic               Characteristic Vector  V'EV=1
                Root    Percent              x1              x2
          0.64162782      75.19      0.23674984      0.00222702
          0.21172068      24.81     -0.11171221      0.00402658
```

I used R to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of E Inverse * H：

```
E=matrix(c(14.652666667,-53.58333333,-53.58333333,47426.041667),  
         nrow=2, ncol=2,byrow = TRUE) 
E
H=matrix(c(7.926,122.48333333,122.48333333,13753.958333), 
         nrow=2, ncol=2,byrow = TRUE) 
H
C=solve(E)%*%H
C
eigen(E)
```

The eigenvalues are same, but the eigenvectors are different with SAS characteristic vectors. 
Can you tell me why or algorithms? Thank you!

Comment: How to compute characteristic vector by proc iml? Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking how to solve this in SAS or in R?

Comment: eigenvectors are only defined up to a scale factor, SAS and R probably use different default scales ...

Comment: Since you have labeled it as an R question , I'm downvoting because BenBolker's point has been answered many times in the Rhelp mailing list when  other persons asked why SA and R do not give the same values. (I had tried removing the [r] tag earlier in the day but someone apparently put it back in.)